# CLI in Go. Displaying a structure of flow

Tags: go

I am trying to write a Command Line Interface in Go. I have did a lot of work so far but i am stuck at the phase where I literally don't know what to do? How can I write a function that displays the input and output files like a flow tree. For example, If I have a parent file A and B,C,D are present in it, next I have G and E,F are present in it. Can anyone help me with this?

The structure will look like:

A

|

|____ B

|____ C

|____D

G

|

|____ E

|

|____ F

Note: I want to print this structure in console.

Answer (score 1):

You have some libraries already specialized in that kind of output.

For instance: [**xlab/treeprint**](https://github.com/xlab/treeprint)

```
fmt.Println(tree.String())

.
├── one
│   ├── subnode1
│   ├── subnode2
│   ├── two
│   │   ├── subnode1
│   │   ├── subnode2
│   │   └── three
│   │       ├── subnode1
│   │       └── subnode2
│   └── subnode3
└── outernode
```

Comment: I will get to it now and see the possibilities. It is very helpful.